import on python and file visibility
there is a problem. there is a set of files in format:
|---- tg_ver
    |---- tg.py
    |---- m
        |---- m_1
            |---- main.py
            |---- cookies.json
            |---- state.txt

        |---- m_2
            |---- main.py
            |---- cookies.json
            |---- state.txt

        |---- m_3
            |---- main.py
            |---- cookies.json
            |---- state.txt

        |---- m_n
            |---- main.py
            |---- cookies.json
            |---- state.txt

After all, Import in the file "tg.py" files "main.py" do not see neighboring files such as "cookies.json", "state.txt", etc.
tg.py:
def start():
    import m.m1.main as m
    m.bot_start()


start()
# ----> EROR: no such file "cookies.json"

during operation, the "main.py" files create log files, they appear in the "tg_ver" directory
Initially, import was supposed to occur during operation, depending on user actions, through the __import__() construction. Then I ran into this problem, tried it with standard import, got the same result.

You missed out the crucial bit of code -- how you tried to open cookies.json. Maybe you did open('cookies.json')?

I think it has to do with relative paths. The name "cookies.json" file is no longer the correct relative path as you execute tg.py. However in your module "main.py", you could write a import os then cookies_path = print(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"cookies.json")). And now you are sure to have the correct path to your json file

Also, there is a typo in your code. It should be import m.m_1.main as m, or the typo is in the directory tree.

When you open a file foo.txt using a relative path (one that does not begin with a /), python (or any program) will create an absolute path by joining the path with the current working directory. So if you are in a different working directory when you run your program, your program will need to use different paths to find the same file.
This example would print the contents of a file called /foo/bar/my/file.txt.
$ cd /foo/bar
$ python3 -c 'print(open("my/file.txt").read())'

Even modules in packages and subpackages will look for files starting in the current working directory of the process and NOT the directory that the module source file can be found in.
A simple way to make sure you always find files by paths relative to your modules is to use the __file__ attribute present in every module loaded from a .py file.
Let's say you have a file structure like:
|---- project
    |---- main.py
    |---- mypackage
        |---- mymod.py
        |---- some.json

To reliably always open some.json from mymod.py you could do.
from pathlib import Path

datafile = Path(__file__).parent / 'some.json'
contents = datafile.read_text()
print(contents)

Using importlib.resources
For more complex cases, you should use importlib.resources. By complex, I mean where the module is not directly found on the filesystem. Perhaps it is packaged in a zip file.
from importlib.resources import read_text

parent_pkg, _ = __name__.rsplit('.', 1)
# if your file is a/b/c.py then __name__ is a.b.c
contents = read_text(parent_pkg, 'some.json')
print(contents)

From python 3.12 this becomes a bit simpler:
from importlib.resources import read_text

contents = read_text(__name__, 'some.json')
print(contents)

importlib.resources provides a bunch of other functions than just read_text(), so check out the documentation if you want the contents of a binary file, or want to be able to write data.

The error occurs because the relative path "state.txt" is resolved relative to the current working directory.
Let's say main.py is like this:
def start():
    with open("state.txt", "r") as f:
        state = f.read()

    print(state)

When you run the script from tg.py, the working directory is tg_ver, not the m_1 directory. Therefore, there is no state.txt to be found.
To fix this in our example, we can modify main.py to use the absolute path of state.txt based on the location of main.py:
import os

def start():
    # Get the directory where main.py is located
    base_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

    # Construct the full path to state.txt
    state_file_path = os.path.join(base_dir, "state.txt")

    with open(state_file_path, "r") as f:
        state = f.read()

    print(state)

This way, state.txt is always located relative to main.py, regardless of where the script is executed.
